# Progress Bar simulating execution time

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, progress-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Coding progress bar advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658435/coding-progress-bar-advice)

I wrote an application in C++ which can encode and decode plain text files (compress and decompress) . Now I am creating gui using Qt and want to add a progress bar showing the compression progress when user runs compression, which is similar to winrar or general setup applications. Is it possible to create such a progress bar representing a percentage of current execution time/total execution time? or can i make an approximation of that like the progress bars showing download status .  What is the general approach to create such progress bars?

Comment: Your question is [overly general](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) for SO. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: There are many other questions on SO with answers to help you, search for "[qt] progress" the qt in brackets searches for tags.

Comment: if it takes just some seconds, it would be possible to just display a QProgressDialog and set the range from 0 to 0. in that way you would get some 'idle' progressbar, bouncing left and right.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to have a thread which does the work, while another thread keeps the UI up-to-date.

You would then have to define a mechanism (in the simplest form, a global variable), using which the thread updating the UI can understand what percentage of the job is done. You can then draw the appropriate widgets etc.

Normally, using (at least) two threads, you would need more than just that shared variable. The thread updating the UI must be able to completely understand what's going on, what new information is available, what action is being taken, etc. Note that it is *the other thread* that is actually doing anything useful. The UI thread would be one who observing the state of the program draws something for the user.

The thread that does the job should be able to estimate its progress. In your case, for example by `number_of_bytes_decoded / total_file_size`. Sometimes, it is not possible to predict the progress, and therefore you would just update the progress to "flash" or whatever, showing that progress is being made, but you can't give a percentage. This happens when you see something inside the progress bar going left and right for example.