# Global progress bar and disabling main window

Tags: qt

My desktop application has many operations which can take a while (for example file is downloading) and I want to disable all UI interactions until file is downloaded. For now I solved this by creating modal dialog with progress and status info. I'm wondering if Qt has some fancy solution for that? For example, in Android API you can easily create global progres like on this picture:
[image]

As you can see, background is nicely shaded. Can I have similar effect with Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use the QProgressDialog, as told in [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626946/qt-how-can-i-put-my-main-window-in-the-background-while-im-processing-with-wind). It should be the proper solution for you...